# Nested attributes problems - paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

3 models

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :regions

    has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :country
    has_many :appartments

    has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :region
    belongs_to :country
    has_attached_file :image,
        :styles => {
          :thumb=> "100x100>",
          :small  => "300x300>",
          :large => "600x600>"
            }

end
```

The edit form

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>

       <% if asset.object.new_record? %>
             <%= asset.file_field :image %>
       <% end %>

   <% end %>
```

My region controller:

```
def edit
 @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])


# For URL like /countries/1/regions/2/edit

    @region = @country.regions.find(params[:id])
    5.times { @country.region.assets.build }
end
```

I get

```
"undefined method `region' for #<Country:0x007fbf8b848198>"
```

Someone ideas?

Comment: Remco. Fix your question formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
5.times { @country.region.assets.build }
```

should be

```
5.times { @region.assets.build }
```

Comment: dont't work. there is no country_id, image_filename, image_content, image_size stored in de DB tables assets.  The region_id record is only in de  BD.

Comment: @user874862 whta country? there should be `region_id`